# Add a variable to the method call path in Python

Tags: python

Can you please tell me how to add a variable to the method call path?

```
Example, i have: 
    my_template = templates.rows.VARS_system.safe_substitute(**service.to_dict())
```

I want to substitute the value of the variable instead of the word VARS:

```
my_template = templates.rows.PROD_system.safe_substitute(**service.to_dict())
....
my_template = templates.rows.STAGE_system.safe_substitute(**service.to_dict())
```

Comment: Use a dictionary.

Comment: I Searched on this topic but I got a little confused. If there would be some small example of what was meant.

Comment: We don't know what `templates` and `templates.rows` are. That would help with the example, but they could be any type (probably class instances, but they might be module/submodule names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `getattr` while looping through a list of names.
It will depend on the type of `templates.rows`, but from the little amount of code given, this might work.

(Untested!)

```
sections = ['PROD', 'STAGE']

for section in sections:
    name = section + '_system'
    attr = getattr(templates.rows, name)
    my_template = attr.safe_substitute(**service.to_dict())
    # Do stuff with my_template
```